# Creating a macro that can selectively format capital letters

Tags: macros, formatting, capitalization, small-caps

For a project my partner and I are working on, our text includes a great number of words in mixed lowercase and smallcaps:

[image: an example]

We're currently doing this with a rather clunky macro:

```
\newcommand{\famword}[5]{%
    #1\textsc{#2}#3\textsc{#4}#5}
```

This allows us to have two "clusters" of smallcaps within a word like this:

```
\famword{a}{k}{i}{l}{ulat}
```

which is just good enough to function without wasting too much of our time. However, since we're inputting a lot of words like this what we'd really *like* to do is have a macro where we could type the command like this:

```
\famword{aKiLulat}
```

and have it automatically convert the capital letters within the command to smallcaps in the document. We've searched for answers on this stack exchange and found a few solutions to adjacent issues, but none that addresses this particular problem.

As an addendum, some of these words contain the "Latin capital letter glottal stop" character Ɂ. Our existing macro deals with this character fine (as far as I can tell it just leaves it unaltered), but just in case any solution exists that would break on this non-ascii character, it won't do.

Does anybody know if this is doable?

Comment: For those of us who aren't linguists: Could you give an example of a word that "contains the 'Latin capital letter glottal stop' character Ɂ"?

Comment: for instance, there are words like eɁaɁa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using modern fonts in conjunction with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, one is (sometimes) able to delegate this this to the font, since OpenType Layout defines a font feature `c2sc` that translates capital letters to small cap letters. Unfortunately, Latin Modern does not contain this feature. When available, one can activate this via `fontspec` feature `Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps`.  Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text} % Font with c2sc feature and italic SC
\newcommand\famword[1]{{\addfontfeatures{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps}#1}}

\begin{document}
\famword{aKiLulat}

\itshape \famword{aKiLulat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nifty! I wasn't aware of the `Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps` option until I read your answer.

Comment: Accepting this because it's what we ended up using -- it even puts the capital glottal stop in smallcaps, which our solution (or bare `\textsc{}`) wasn't doing!

Answer (score 17):

The `tokcycle` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle) can be used for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\famword[1]{%
  \resettokcycle%
  \Characterdirective{\ifcat A##1\ifnum`##1<`Z\addcytoks{%
    \textsc{\char\numexpr32+`##1\relax}}\else
    \addcytoks{##1}\fi\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}%
  \tokcyclexpress{#1}%
  \the\cytoks%
}
\begin{document}
\famword{aKiLulat or even aK\textit{iLulat}!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I commented, to get italic small caps, you need a font that supports it, such as `\usepackage{newtxtext}`:

[image]

If one prefers an invocation that is more environment-based, rather than macro-based, there is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\tokcycleenvironment\famword%
  {\ifcat A##1\ifnum`##1<`Z\addcytoks{%
    \textsc{\char\numexpr32+`##1\relax}}\else
    \addcytoks{##1}\fi\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}% <-CHARACTERS
  {\processtoks{##1}}% <-GROUPS
  {\addcytoks{##1}}% <-MACROS
  {\addcytoks{##1}}% <-SPACES
\begin{document}
\famword aKiLulat or even aK\textit{iLulat}!\endfamword
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks so much for this answer! who knew there was a package that did this... is it possible to make the small caps also italicized when the rest is italicized? or is that just a matter of putting the scope of `\textit{}` over `\famword` rather than vice-versa?

Comment: @Sparksbet The problem is that with the default CM font, there is no version of italic small caps.  If you use a font that supports it, it should properly italicize.  As to my `tokcycle` package, its purpose is to provide a tool for cycling through a list of tokens, and "doing something."  Here, the "something" I choose to do is to apply small caps to alphabetic letters that are initially capitalized.  I have to first lowercase them, and then apply the `\textsc`.

Comment: In the next latex version `\textit` + `\textsc` will combine to an italic small caps. The prerelease has just been uploaded and tomorrow it should be possible to test this with `pdflatex-dev` and similar dev-versions.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It consists of (a) a main Lua function called `uc2sc` (short for "uppercase to smallcaps", I suppose) and an auxiliary Lua function called `makesc` which, together, do most of the work and (b) a LaTeX macro called `\famword` that acts as a wrapper for the `uc2sc` function. The Lua functions employ Lua's versatile built-in `string.gsub` and `string.lower` functions.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function makesc ( x )
   return ( "\\textsc{" .. x:lower() .. "}" )
end
function uc2sc ( s )
   return ( s:gsub ( "%u", makesc ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX wrapper macro:
\newcommand\famword[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(uc2sc("#1"))}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text} % a font with italic-smallcap letters

\begin{document}
\famword{aKiLulat} 

\itshape \famword{aKiLulat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using uppercase in the input to mean small caps in the output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\famword}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([A-Z]+) } { \c{spark_lc:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \spark_lc:n { \textsc { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\famword{aKiLulat}

\end{document}
```

This only touches uppercase letters.

[image]